# What's the point of the [commercial] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

My interest is triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991829/envato-codecanyon-script-can-i-sell-it). The [commercial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commercial) tag itself looks suitable enough; the question, however, doesn't. It quickly got decorated with 5 downvotes and seems to be heading straight to the bin.

Puzzled, I checked [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commercial) - and failed to find any questions suitable for the *current* SO format, all of them are mostly about law/license-related issues. But shouldn't those be asked at Programmers at least? As I see it, these questions are good candidates for 'find me...' closure reasoning, no?

Comment: IMO legal issues are off-topic for SO, even if they're legal issues regarding the use of software or software libraries.

Comment: @Ajedi32: if the tag was [tag:commercial-license], would issues of license tainting and bundling be on-topic?

Comment: It appears that the vast majority of questions under this tag are off-topic licensing questions which should probably just be deleted.

Comment: @smci: questions about licenses tend to be legal rather than technical, so they still wouldn't be on-topic for SO.

Comment: Haha I've just found my favourite tag thanks to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal it even says in it's description that it's not suitable for SO

Comment: @Dunno Looks like most questions under that tag should be closed. If you want to get the Marshall badge, that tag is a good place to start.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe we should burninate that tag.

With only the word "commercial" it's a meta-tag. Commercial what? Commercial who? TV commercial?

The Tag Wiki gives a little more info:

> Commercial software can refer both to software that is charged for and software that is intended for commercial use.

The first usage isn't useful for Stack Overflow; if you have a problem with a commercial product, you should use the tag associated with that particular product (or create it if it isn't there and you have enough rep).

The second usage... far too general. From an SO point of view, the fact that software is intended to be commercial doesn't make a lot of difference. If a question requires that the answers satisfy certain legal and/or quality requirements, those should be in the question.

Questions about licensing, as you observed, are better fit for [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) anyway - with the usual caveat that Software Engineering  too [has some restrictions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/licensing/info) on the questions they allow.

Answer (score 6):

Because you get tag points and tag badges, any tag should **meet the criteria of being a skill**. In other words, is somebody an expert on "Commercial"? No. It's not possible to be an expert on that, since it's far too general. As such, this tag should be removed.

Exception to this rule would be if there was a widely known product Commercial, or something created by company called Commercial. In which case a tag should clearly state that.